# Can someone show me a working jsFiddle or Plunker for angular-material text inputs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have tried to do it but it turns out unstyled. I can't find anything on stackoverflow that suggests that the angular-material library can run outside of the angular website.

[Inputs in material design are not themed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009738/inputs-in-material-design-are-not-themed)

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/134/

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

    app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {});
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl" layout="column" md-theme="green">
        <md-toolbar class="md-primary">
            <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">
          Top Secret Project
        </h1>
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-button class="md-raised">Button test</md-button>
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <form name="projectForm">
                <md-input-container>
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <input md-maxlength="30" required name="description" ng-model="project.description">
                    <div ng-messages="projectForm.description.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        <div ng-message="md-maxlength">The name has to be less than 30 characters long.</div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container>
                    <label>Client Name</label>
                    <input required name="clientName" ng-model="project.clientName">
                    <div ng-messages="projectForm.clientName.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container>
                    <label>Hourly Rate (USD)</label>
                    <input required type="number" step="any" name="rate" ng-model="project.rate" min="800" max="4999" required>
                    <div ng-messages="projectForm.rate.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">You've got to charge something! You can't just <b>give away</b> a Missile Defense System.</div>
                        <div ng-message="min">You should charge at least $800 an hour. This job is a big deal... if you mess up, everyone dies!</div>
                        <div ng-message="max">$5,000 an hour? That's a little ridiculous. I doubt event Bill Clinton could afford that.</div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
            </form>
        </md-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The requirement to post some code exists for a reason. You're not allowed to post a jsFiddle link and no code. Please read: [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: are we sure the world's not flat too?

Comment: Thanks for the head's up @EdCottrell, been too busy to realize.

Comment: @charlietfl that's an interesting thing to consider

Comment: I believe the issue here is actually some sort of conflict between ngAngular and ngMessages!  I'm experiencing the same problem myself, but the styling returns once I remove 'ngMessages' from my app's dependencies.  The real question is why do they conflict and how can we get around this because ngMessages is really convenient for forms.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it to work. http://geoyws.github.io/angular-mall

```
<md-content>
  <md-input-container>
    <md-text-float type="text" class="" label="username" ng-model="signUp.username" name="username" required></md-text-float>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container>
    <md-text-float type="password" class="" label="password" ng-model="signUp.password" name="password" required></md-text-float>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container>
    <md-text-float type="password" class="" label="repeat password" ng-model="signUp.repeatPassword" name="repeatPassword" required></md-text-float>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container>
    <md-text-float type="email" class="" label="email" ng-model="signUp.email" name="email" required></md-text-float>
  </md-input-container>
</md-content>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use this?

```
<md-text-float label="Description" flex ng-model="project.description"> </md-text-float>
```